# iPhone 5 video: continuous shooting without creating independent clips

Tags: iphone

I'm shooting some doco footage using the iPhone 5. I'm looking for a way to shoot "tape" style. I don't want independant clips when I stop recording. Just want to append clips back to back continuously like pausing and recording does on any video camera.

I'd rather not combine clips at the end. If there's a way to avoid this that would be perfect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If there is, you'd have to find an app that does it and it would effectively be doing the same thing of simply appending the clips automatically for you.  In a good NLE, it should just be a matter of dropping a multi-selection of clips on to a timeline to have it assemble them back to back.

Answer (score 1):

At this time the iPhone 5 does NOT have that feature. The only thing you can do is download an application such as Qik or other recording in the appstore which they have a feature such pause or zoom.